# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera problem with Navigation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an alert that asks user if he/she want a picture from Photo App or Camera (`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`).

When the user selects the image in both case, I push a view controller like that:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{       
        UIImage *pickedImage = [info
                                objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        PhotoViewController* controller = [[PhotoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController" bundle:nil photo:pickedImage];
            [picker pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

When users choose for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` there is no problem, because my controller will be inside the UINavigatorController. So user can go back to previous Navigation.

But when users choose for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` the UINavigation is not in the top of my view. I need it because I want to create a CANCEL button.

I use the same view in both case.

Do you have a suggestion for me, please? How could I see the UINavigation from the UIImagePicker in my PhotoViewController after user takes a picture?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code in my PhotoViewControler to solve my problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  ...
  ...
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  ...
  ...
}
```